# Save and fetch JSON data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I am working on a project that has multiple sets of data of different types like `SUGAR`, `BloodPressure`, etc. I want to store all data in a single table in JSON format, but I don't know how to differentiate that data when I will fetch it later on.

Comment: Use different kind of model/objects in your SQL database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that by using different data models but its very confusing and time consuming to manage different tables. Will you please guide me with some lines of code please?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a field that will tell you what type it is. For example `"dataType" : "sugar"` or `"dataType" : "bloodpresure"`

Comment: I would personally add a column to the MySQL table to hold the type of data. This way you will be able to distinguish records and "filter" data with queries.

Comment: Fixed grammatical errors, improved title by removing reference to Objective-C and correcting reference to MySQL (assuming it is correct based on the selected tags), removed tags: `ios` and `objective-c` because this issue seems to be too broad to be directly related to either.